# Emberjs, Duplicating a dynamic object with 'copy' action

Tags: ember.js, duplicates, action, clone

I am looking to create an action that will duplicate a selected object (with a new ID) in a list of objects.

```
{#each itemController="recordCategory"}}
  <button {{action 'copy'}} ></button>
{{/each}}
```

This is what I have but ember does not know what copy() is even though http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Copyable.html specifies that the method exists and should be used.

```
save: function(){
  var recordCategory = this.get('model');
  recordCategory.copy();
  recordCategory.save();
  this.transitionToRoute('recordCategory', recordCategory);
},
```